# A wifi modem powersupply input

Tags: router, battery, adapter

I'm planning to make a DIY UPS (Do It Yourself - Uninterruptable Power Supply).

Question: Can a WiFi modem unit with 12 volts and 1 amps input can handle a battery that is also 12 volts but 30 amps?

Comment: Can a 30A supply at same voltage feed a 1A load? Certainly. Keep a 1A trickle charge regulator on it 12.5V lead acid.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by "a battery that is also 12 volts but 30 Amps". I assume you mean the battery can provide up to 30 Amps. In this case it should be fine.

Keep in mind though that you might need a voltage regulator for the batteries output (without one the battery's voltage with 1 amp usage/load will be higher then with 30 amps usage/load).

A word of advice: if you couldn't answer this question yourself (it's rather simple) you might not have sufficient background knowledge to build a UPS. Unless you take the time to acquire the required knowledge, I would strongly advise against it since there are safety issues involved here.